# Grails Date Constraints

Tags: validation, grails, groovy

I have an domain class with a constraint, which allows users to be at least 18 years old.

This is working:

```
birthday(nullable: false, max:new Date(use(TimeCategory){18.years.ago.getTime()}))
```

But why is this not working?

```
birthday(nullable: false, max:(use(TimeCategory){18.years.ago}))
```

Ago is actually returning an object of type java.util.Date.

Or best would be of course this:

```
birthday(nullable: false, max: 18.years.ago)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [MagicNumbers plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/magic-numbers) and use **18.years.ago.toDate()**

Comment: Sorry that did not work for me. It does not recognize the years property.

Answer (score 0):

The type is wrong.  Note that your date is a `java.sql.Date`, not a `java.util.Date`.

```
use (TimeCategory) {
    assert 18.years.ago.class == java.sql.Date
}
```

This is an ugly little implementation detail.  Try this in your constraint:

```
birthday(nullable: false, max:(use(TimeCategory){18.years.ago  as Date}))
birthday(nullable: false, max: 18.years.ago  as Date)
```

If you mixin the TimeCategory, e.g. in BootStrap.groovy, you'll be able to just write the second version.  The mixin can be done like so:

```
Integer.metaClass.mixin(groovy.time.TimeCategory)
```

Comment: But the documentation is stating that getAgo returns java.util.Date: http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/time/BaseDuration.html but I will try it asap and will give feedback

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`, so the docs are not incorrect.  But I think my original comment is wrong.  Since the sql version is a subclass, it should work wherever a regular date does.  It's interesting that `getTime()`, which converts to a long, works.  What is the declared data type of birthday?

Comment: The declared type is java.util.Date, but even if ago returns java.util.Date it does not work. To create a new java.util.Date with time works. It's really suspect. I am still trying around.

Comment: The mixin did not work for me. The only statement working for me is the above one in my question.